# Line on canvas disappears after redrawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, line

When I input a new value for the angle, the line is redrawn quickly correctly, but then disappears. I think it might be that the input value is refreshed and set to undefined again but i'm not sure. How can I make it keep the line with the correct angle.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//Global Variables
rad2deg = 180/(Math.PI);

var mouse = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
};

function findAngle(e){
    var ang = (Math.atan((720-mouse.y)/(e.pageX-mouse.x)))*rad2deg;
    $("#angle").val(ang+"°");
}

function Draw(firstX, firstY, lastX){
    cvs = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    cvs.clearRect(0,0,1080,720);
    cvs.beginPath();
    cvs.moveTo(firstX, firstY);
    cvs.lineTo(lastX, 720);
    cvs.closePath();
    cvs.lineWidth=5;
    cvs.stroke();
};

function drawUserAngle(){
    enter = 0;
    mod = enter % 2;
    alert($("#angle").val());
    var angle = $("#angle").val()/rad2deg;  
    if($("#angle").val() !== 'undefined'){
        var x = 540 - (180/(Math.tan(angle)));
        Draw(x,540,540); 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("canvas").click(function(e){
        if(mouse.x != -1 && mouse.y != -1){
            Draw(mouse.x, mouse.y, e.pageX);
            findAngle(e);
            mouse.x = -1;
            mouse.y = -1;
        }else{
        mouse.x = e.pageX;
        mouse.y = e.pageY;
        }
    });
});

</script>
<form>
Angle: <input type="text" id="angle">
<button onclick="drawUserAngle()">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard action when a button is clicked is to perform a submit. You can disable this by changing

```
<button onclick="drawUserAngle()">Enter</button>
```

into

```
<button onclick="drawUserAngle(); return false">Enter</button>
```

The reason the line is drawn briefly is that the page refreshes on submit.